# Is this a stack?

Tags: java, stack

Is this code a stack?

How I can make it better?

This is my first one.

Can i do this using ArrayList?

```
public class Stack implements IADT {
private final int[] stackArray = new int[10];
private int top;
private int nr;
public Stack(){
    top = -1;
}
@Override
public String pop() {
    return Integer.toString(stackArray[top--]);
}
@Override
public String peek() {
    return Integer.toString(stackArray[top]);
}
@Override
public void push(String value) {
    //...
}
```

I didn't added the isEmpty() method.

Comment: To a certain degree, this is about reviewing your code; codereview.stackexchange.com might be a good place too.

Comment: It's ok if it's your first stack, don't worry. Scientists estimate that you'll stop making mistakes somewhere around your fourteenth stack.

Comment: You could add error handling for overflow and underflow. You might also make it generic. Finally, you could use a `Collection` instead of an array.

Comment: I would do it using a `Node<T>` class since it will be useful when you move onto other structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.
But you can add checking for overflow, underflow.

And this will be better if you'll try using collections.